# Can you Help me with a A1466 MacBook Air That won't boot no matter what I try?

Tags: macbook-pro, startup, kernel-panic, single-user

So, my brother's MacBook Air isn't working anymore. I have had my fair share of problems with my macs (2011 and 2012 macbook Pros, imacs, macBook airs,etc), and I've always been able to resolve these problems because i have a good knowledge of computers, especially macs ^^.

So, the MacBook Air here isn't booting. It takes a horrible amount of time to get the boot progress bar to 100% and when it reaches 100%, it never gives the login screen. It's super fast until it hits 60%, then it's a little slower, and around 90% it's horribly slow. It does the same "stop at 100%" thing when I try to boot off the recovery partition (cmd R) and when I boot it from a install usb.

The good thing, is that it boots to single user mode, from there i've been able to execute fsck, but it tells me that the Ssd is all good... I've concluded that there must be some bad kexts and plists in the libraries. So i searched the kexts that are on my macbook pro with a clean install and deleted all the non nessecary kexts on the MBA. It changed nothing. I also deleted some big files on the Disk because there was not a lot of space left. But nothing changed.
Still doesnt boot, doesnt boot from recovery nor a usb. 
Also, when I boot it in Verbose mode, it seems that it's stuck in some kinda boot loop due to Airport (ARPT giving what looks like status messages over and over). So this could be some hardware error? idk.

Now I have several options left. I can boot it to Traget Disk mode and reset/reformat/reinstall it from my daily driver MBP 2012, but i'd have to buy a thunderbolt to thunderbolt cable (plus i'm not even shure the minidisplay port on my MBP is thunderbolt x) ), or I could create a bootable instal of macOS on a usb stick, but i'm not sure if it'll even boot.

What Do you think is the problem on here?
I've Eliminated these problems:
-Not enough space
-Bad Kexts, plists, drivers, etc
-Cache
Do you think it's a Hardware problem, do you think a target mode reset/reinstall through a known good mac would help, do you think a bootable copy of macOS on a USB would help?

Thank you all ^^
Heres the Verbose ARPT logs:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/zxPJG.jpg

PS: I've tried NVRam and smc reset first thing, didnt help....

Comment: You listed several options you had left, why not give them a go?  It doesnt cost anything to boot from the USB installer?  Why negate the option as “not sure if it’ll even boot” before trying?

Comment: Well, I tried off the USB installer, it does the same "stuck at 100%"thing. I am really considering Taking the Hdd frolm my MacBook Pro, sticking it in a usb enclosure, and booting mac os off it on the macbook air. I'm really not sure tho, becausi I have a Bootcamp partition on the MacBook Pro's Hdd That i Really dont want to lose. I was talking about Creating a Bootable USB drive, like install macos on the usb.